# Translation Golf XII - Norse Mythology de Neil Gaiman

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

He pensado en publicar una nueva entrada, por si alguien anda aburrido y quiere participar.

Esta es la descripción de uno de los mundos que componen el universo de la mitología nórdica, de la mano de Neil Gaiman.

> To the south was Muspell. Muspell was fire. Everything there glowed and burned. Muspell was light where Niflheim was gray, molten lava where the mist world was frozen. The land was aflame with the roaring heat of a blacksmith's fire; there was no solid earth, no sky. Nothing but sparks and spurting heat, molten rocks and burning embers.
>
> Neil Gaiman: Norse Mythology.

Una posible traducción libre (304 caracteres) sería:

> Al sur se encontraba Muspell. Muspell era fuego. Todo allí resplandecía y ardía. Muspell era luz donde Niflheim era gris, lava fundida donde el mundo de las nieblas se encontraba congelado. El mundo estaba en llamas con el rugir ardiente de la fragua de un herrero; no había tierra sólida ni cielo. Nada salvo chispas y chorreante calor, piedra fundida y rescoldos ardientes.

Como siempre, la traducción con menos caracteres que respete el sentido  de la original gana la partida.

---

Update 1: Muspell y Niflheim son dos de los nuevo mundos de la mitología nórdica. Muspell es el mundo del fuego y Niflheim el de la bruma gris y fría.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me puedo resistir...

### <strike>232 229</strike> 231 caracteres

> Muspell, al sur, era fuego, allí todo relucía y ardía. Si Niflheim era gris, Muspell era luz y lava viscosa donde el mundo nebuloso era hielo. La tierra flagraba cual rugiente horno de herrero: no había suelo firme ni cielo. Solo chispas, chorros cálidos, roca derretida y brasas ardientes.

Licencias:

- [Nebuloso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QKJi5Z1): Que abunda en nieblas, o cubierto de ellas.
- [Flagrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I2ZEBBn): Arder o resplandecer como fuego o llama.

Cambios:

- *Nada mas* por *solo*. Cortesía de Brian H.

Más cambios:

- Reordenación de la segunda frase tras los comentarios del OP.

Comment: @walen pues la verdad es que no me sonaba (demasiado) raro, pero entiendo que es una duda razonable. ¿Te animas a plantearla en el sitio como una nueva pregunta?

Comment: "Al sur, Muspell era fuego" no me suena bien, si no supiera por el texto original que Muspell es un lugar, pensaría que Muspel, sea lo que sea, cuando está en el sur es fuego.

Comment: y podrías cambiar "Nada mas chispas..." por "Solo chispas..."

Comment: @BrianH. ¡Gracias por la idea! Sobre lo de que Muspell es una ciudad, al decir "al sur" ya se entiende que Muspell es una ciudad. Si fuera una persona diría "en el sur". En todo caso, si tienes dudas (como las puedo tener yo ahora) te propongo lo mismo que a walen: plantea una pregunta en el sitio sobre el uso de "al sur" y "en el sur" para referirse a la localización de sitios o personas, y así le damos más vida al sitio.

Comment: Sugiero cambiarlo por "Muspell, al sur, era fuego". Simplemente reordenamos. Contexto: se están describiendo los mundo del la mitología. Al norte (de la nada, paradójicamente) Niflheim, frío y niebla, al sur Muspell. Veo más problema en ese "se tornaba", porque lo que se describe es un contraste (uno era frío, el otro ardiente) no que uno _cambia_. Donde los dos mundos se tocan es donde terminan naciendo los gigantes y los Aesir, cierto, pero eso se describe luego, y leyendo esa línea yo entiendo que el  frío de Niflheim cambia a calor de Muspell.

Comment: Eres el ganador de esta edición!

Answer (score 3):

Este es mi primer intento en translation-golf, a ver que sale.

### <strike>263</strike> 260 caracteres

> Al sur estaba Muspell. Muspell era fuego. Todo allí brillaba y ardía. Muspell era luz donde Niflheim era gris, lava fundida donde el mundo de bruma estaba helado. La tierra ardía con el rugiente calor de la llama de un herrero; no había tierra firme, ni cielo. Solo chispas y chorros de calor, roca derretida y ascuas en llamas.

No estoy del todo contento con la redundancia en el uso del verbo arder

> Todo allí brillaba y ardía

y

> La tierra ardía con...

Tampoco me  gusta como ha quedado "La tierra ardía..." seguido de "no había tierra..."

en general me parece una traducción simplilla, pero bueno, lo importante es participar :)

---

#### Cambios

- cambio niebla por bruma: -1 caracter
- cambio derretida por fundida: -2 caracteres

Comment: Puedes añadir  ##263 caracteres  como cabecera de tu texto (lo haría yo si fuese una pregunta normal, pero al ser _communiti wiki_ luego sale que es 50% mía y 50% tuya y prefiero no hacerlo para dejar constancia de de quié es enta entrada del juego). He usado el contador de caracteres que viene en la pregunta (JSfiddle). La verdad es que es una entrada que conserba muy bien el sentido original. Ahora, a intentar reducir el número de caracteres!

Comment: @Diego gracias, no me habia dado cuenta del jsfiddle, ya le he puesto el numero de caracteres y he hecho algunos cambios, que me quitan 3 caracteres :)

Answer (score 2):

### 246 caracteres

> Al sur estaba Muspell, que era fuego, y allí todo brillaba y ardía. Muspell era luz, y Niflheim, lava fundida gris allí donde se helaba el mundo de bruma. El país ardía con el rugiente calor de una fragua, y no había tierra firme ni cielo, nada más que chispas, chorros de calor, rocas fundidas y brasas ardientes.